# Pass a value between a Window and a page in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am developing a software with WPF and i would like pass a parameter(textbox) between the Window(MainWindow)  to a page(it is situated in a Frame) ...do you have any idea as do it?

Thansk so much my friends...
BB

EDITED :
Well i have a textbox in the MAINWINDOW with the Value "DB2012_2013"  then the code of the frame is this one :

```
    <Frame  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" LoadCompleted="frSample_LoadCompleted" Navigating="frSample_Navigating" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="frSample" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{Binding SelectedItem.XamlFilePath, ElementName=CategoryTreeView, FallbackValue=Welcome.xaml, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

then when i choose the page to open i would pass the value of the textbox in the new page ... to use this value for some query to do ..

Comment: Does the passing of the value from the MainWindow to the Page immediately trigger the search-action? Or is there some user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataContext and WPF Binding feature.

You can set DataContext belong to MainWindow.
Do you need pass data into Frame or UI component textbox?

```
<TextBox Name="textBox" Text="Text"></TextBox>
<Frame DataContext="{Binding ElementName=textBox,Path=DataContext}" Background="AliceBlue" Width="200">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the MainWindow is the container of the Frame then the Frame will change many page and then i each time change page i need this value(text) to store the data from the database...then i should use this value to store the data so i should find out the method how pass it and use in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You could make all pages implement an interface that has a property for the desired value.

```
public interface IPageWithValue
{
    string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever you change to the page, set the property value from the main window, whenever you leave the page, read the property.

Have your pages implement that interface.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
App.Current.MainWindow.TextBoxName.Text

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are more elegant ways than making the textbox variable public. Also, without a cast to the main window's class this won't work.